# addWidget doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, widget, addition, qgraphicsscene

I want to add a widget to the `QGraphicsScene` by clicking a button but it
doesn't work. Anybody any idea what I'm doing wrong ? I setup the `QGraphicsScene` like this:

```
ui->setupUi(this);

mScene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
mNodeView = new QNodeView(ui->tabWidget);
ui->NodeGraphicsView->addWidget(mNodeView);

mNodeView->setScene(mScene);
mNodeView->show();
```

Add the widget to the `QGraphicsScene`

```
void MainWindow::on_actionTextNode_triggered()
{
    QNodeWidget *_nodeWidget = new QNodeWidget(mNodeView);
    mScene->addWidget(_nodeWidget);

    mNodeView->show();
}
```

Comment: Did you get error like QGraphicsProxyWidget::setWidget: cannot embed widget... ?

Comment: Did you try calling `_nodeWidget->show()` right after adding it to `mScene`?

Comment: What is a QNodeWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you try set parent to `_nodeWidget`, try to do it without parent:

```
QNodeWidget *_nodeWidget = new QNodeWidget;
```

Is it work?

Comment: But now I get a segfault wehn I try to delete the Object.

Comment: Just forgot deleteLater();

Answer (score 0):

When you add a widget to a scene, it's added as a QProxyWidget at position (0,0).

If you can't see the widget, it's possible that it's just not in view. First, check that the call to addWidget returns a valid pointer and if so, focus the view on the widget with a call to fitInWindow: -

```
QNodeWidget *_nodeWidget = new QNodeWidget(mNodeView);
QGraphicsProxyWidget* pProxy = mScene->addWidget(_nodeWidget);

mNodeView->fitInWindow(pProxy);
```

If you didn't get a valid pointer to the proxy widget, then there's a problem with the QNodeWidget class.